# Asp.net core View Design and ajax in view component

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.NET Core app, I have this customer view:

[image]

I have divided the view into Part 1 and Part 2. Actually I need to achieve these 2 things in ASP.NET Core MVC:

1. When the user clicks the Search button, load the Part 2 component.
2. When the user clicks pagination in part 2, I need to refresh only part 2 component.

I have decided do the part 1 as a Razor view and Part 2 as a view component. Also I want to achieve refreshing the component when the user clicks Search button (part1) and clicks the pagination (inside same component)

1. Please let me know whether I did correct or not?
2. How to send the page index to component to reload the the component with ajax when page index is clicked?

Thanks in advance. I don't expect entire code. Please let me know the logic to refresh the component.

This is the code for pagination.

```
<nav aria-label="Pagination" class="col-12">
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
        <li class="page-item @prevDisabled">
            <a class="page-link" 
                asp-controller="Home"  asp-action="getcust" 
                asp-route-id="@(Model.Stocks.PageIndex - 1)"
                aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        @foreach (var i in Model.Stocks.PageIndexesToDisplay)
        {
            var activeClass = i.IsActive ? "active" : "";

            <li class="page-item @activeClass"><a class="page-link"  
                                         asp-controller="Home" asp-action="getcust" 
                                        asp-route-id="@(i.Index)">@i.Index</a></li>
        }
        <li class="page-item @nextDisabled">
            <a class="page-link" 
                 asp-controller="Home" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="getcust" 
                asp-route-Id="@(Model.Stocks.PageIndex + 1)"
                aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please let me know whether I did correct or not?

Nothing wrong with your implementation, looks okay. Just a side note; you may consider partial view as well instead of view component.

> How to send the page index to component to reload the the component with ajax when page index is clicked?

Invoking a view component can be done via `InvokeAsync` method:

```html
@await Component.InvokeAsync("PagingList", new { pageNo = 1, pageSize = 10, /* ..etc. */ })
```

or you can invoke the view component as a taghelper:

```html
<vc:paging-list page-no="1" page-size="10">
</vc:priority-list>
```

For more details see [Invoking a view component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#invoking-a-view-component)

---

Another approach can be done with partial view instead of view component. I've published a sample repo similar to what you want to achive but with Asp.Net Core Razor Pages and partial views *and a reliable pagination control :)* you can check it here:

- [Paging Sample Project](https://github.com/LazZiya/PagingSampleProject)
- [Paging with Ajax Live Demo](http://demo.ziyad.info/en/PagingAjax)
- [Ajax Request Using Inline Attributes](http://demo.ziyad.info/en/AjaxRequest)